# does opera support Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, browser, opera

I'm writing a greasemonkey script, using jquery $.ajax to get a json data and motify the DOM.

I add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* head in my server script, it works fine in current version chrome and firefox, but not opera.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Opera is expected to add [support for CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) in version 12 (which has not been released at the time of writing).

update: Opera 12 supports CORS.